# Qt:Signals and Slots vs C++:Message Passing

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have two classes

```
class Car
{
// class Car related methods
public:
setDriversName(QString);
private:
String driversName_;    // This information comes from class DriversName

//Must get the drivers name info, when a particular event in this object occurs;
}

class DriversName
{
//class DriversName related methods
String getDriversName();
private:
String driversName_;
}
```

So, now i want to communicate between the two classes, more specifically i want class `Car` to get the driver's name from the `DriversName` class **when a particular event occours in Car Object**.

So far i have these two ways,

```
C++ Message passing:

class Car
{
// class Car related methods
public:
setDriversNameObject(DriversName& );
setDriversName()
{
   driversName_ =  DriversName.getDriversName();
}

private:
DriversName driversName_;    // So after setting the Driverclass object, i can directly 
//access the driver's name, whenever the event occurs
String driversName_;
}

class DriversName
{
//class DriversName related methods
String getDriversName();

private:
DriversName driversName_;
}
```

OR

```
Qt

In mainWindow class:

connect(carObject,eventHasOccured(),this,updateDriversName());


void MainWindow::updateDriversName()
{
    carObject->setDriversName(driversNameObject.getDriversName);
}

Class Car
{
    Q_OBJECT
    signals:
    emit eventHasOccured();

    public:
    setDriversNameObject(DriversName& );

    private:
    DriversName driversName_;              
}

Class DriversName
{
    Q_OBJECT

    String getDriversName();

    private:
    DriversName driversName_;    
}
```

Both the Solutions will definitely work.
Here are my questions:

> 1) Is there any flaw in the above methods, with respect to OO
>   principles.
>
> 2) Which is the most standard way this situation can be
>   dealt with ?
>
> 3) is there any other better method to handle the given
>   situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there any flaw in the above methods, with respect to OO principles.

The first approach couples the `Car` method closely to the `DriversName` class.

The second couples your application to Qt. If you use it throughout your whole application anyway, that's not much of a problem, but it should be considered. Also, it moves business logic code into the mainwindow class, which might not be such a good idea.

> 2) Which is the most standard way this situation can be dealt with ?

There is no "one definitive way" of doing this. Just better and worse ones.

> 3) is there any other better method to handle the given situation.

For the "pure C++" approach, you could introduce an abstract interface for listening to driver name changes (or maybe even more generically for listening to generic name changes).
What I'm referring to here is basically implementing the [Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633808/the-observer-pattern-further-consideration-and-generalised-c-implementation) pattern. A simplified implementation could e.g. look like this:

```
class NameChangeListener
{
public:
    virtual void onNameChange(std::string const & newName) =0;
};

// This assumes change is initiated in DriversName class - not sure if this is correct
// Your code doesn't show the actual triggering of the change
class DriversName
{
public:
// ... other stuff
    setNameChangeListener(NameChangeListener* ncl)
    {
        changeListener = ncl;
    }
    void setName(std::string const & newName)
    {
        // ... other stuff
        if (changeListener)
            changeListener->onNameChange(newName);
    }
private:
    // ..
    NameChangeListener* changeListener;
};

class Car: public NameChangeListener
{
public:
// ... other stuff
    void onNameChange(std::string const & newName) {
        driversName = newName;
    }
};

// somewhere outside:
Car c1;
DriversName n;
n.setNameChangeListener(c1);
```

For the Qt approach, it might be good to introduce an additional "Controller" class encapsulating such relations, instead of doing it directly in the main window.

Comment: Thanks, But can you give an example to demonstrate `introducing an abstract interface for listening to driver name changes (or maybe even more generically for listening to generic name changes).`

Comment: A really good intro into the new world of observer patters...A really good example, and an exception answer, in the link posted about observer patterns...

Answer (score 1):

A few more details on top of nyarlathotep's answer:

1) If you definitely need the update to take place *when a particular event occurs*, then the first solution is not enough because it does not handle events; one should explicitly call `Car`'s `setDriversName()`. You do need a signal/slot, or callback mechanism in general, like the second solution. It that case, I think you would rather need something like

```
connect(driversNameObject,nameChanged(string),carObject,setDriversName(string));
```

where neither the application/main window nor the `carObject` need to know anything about a `driversNameObject`. Besides that, I think there are a number of little errors in your second solution (e.g., there is no `setDriversName` method in `Car`.

2) and 3) I would personally avoid QT's signal/slot mechanism if I am not already working in a QT project. This mechanism bypasses the C++ language entirely and needs source file preprocessing by its own tools. One consequence is that everything (like method names) is processed as a string, before the compiler has any chance for checking. Another is that you need a specific way to build your project that is way more complicated than necessary and would make the use of other libraries more difficult.

As for more "pure C++" solutions, I bet e.g. [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals.html) would do the job, but again it would probably bring too many complexities that you don't need.

I have developed a pure-C++ abstract interface that mimics exactly the behavior of QT signals/slots based on [delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates), but this involves low-level stuff internally like casting to `void*`. An alternative would be of course to use `std::function` in the internals. It is still not completely generic in handling all function-call language features, e.g. methods in derived classes, overloading, virtual methods, default arguments, and so on (but neither is Boost.Signals). I intend to re-implement it in C++11 using variadic templates before completing it.

Again, I am (still) not aware of a perfect or de facto standard solution.

Comment: Correction: In Qt5 signals and slots get verfied at compile time.(there is not SIGNAL() and SLOT() macros)

Comment: @Nazar554: You must have never used Qt 5 then, because those old macros are *definitely* there, and you can use both Qt4- and Qt5-style signals/slots. It'd otherwise be a disaster when porting code. You need to explicitly use the new-style signals and slots to get compile-time verification.

Comment: @KubaOber i meant that you don't use SIGNAL() and SLOT() when using new connect() style, i.e. names are not converted to strings