# C++ Event Handling

Tags: c#, c++, events, unix, delegates

i want to achieve an C# like Event Handling in Standard C++ (UNIX) like the following Code:

```
public class connection{

    public delegate void Message(object sender, string text);
    public event Message doMessage = null;

    //called from within a Thread or something alike
    private void MessageReceived(string Message){
        if (this.doMessage != null)
        {
            this.doMessage(this, Message);
        }
    }
}

public class Main{
    Connection con;

    public Main()
    {
        this.con = new Connection();
        this.con.doMessage += con_doMessage;
    }

    void con_doMessage(object sender, string message)
    {
        txtMain.Text = txtMain.Text + Environment.NewLine + message;
    }
}
```

I googled my fingertips bloody but all i found was Events firing, but not to an overlaying class like in my Example.

In fact, i'm new to Standard C++, maybe there is an easy way to get Data to the overlaying class, by firing it from within the class and i just didn't see it yet.

But yeah, as said, i have no clue and would be thankfull for some advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::function` as a callback:

```
void printSomething() { std::cout << "event!" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    std::function<void()> onEvent;
    onEvent = &printSomething;
    onEvent(); // prints "event!"
}
```

---

If you want *C#-style* delegates, use `std::vector<std::function<...>>`:

```
struct Delegate {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs;
    template<class T> Delegate& operator+=(T mFunc) { funcs.push_back(mFunc); return *this; }
    void operator()() { for(auto& f : funcs) f(); }
};

int main() {
    Delegate delegate;
    delegate += []{ std::cout << "hello, "; };
    delegate += []{ std::cout << "world!" << endl; };
    delegate(); // prints "hello, world!"
}
```

Or just copy my `ssvu::Delegate` class, [available here](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/Delegate/Delegate.h).

Comment: Yeah, things like this i found, but how do i fire the Event from, in my example, within the connection class, and get the Handler in my Main Class to receive the data?

Comment: Can't you have the `Delegate delegate;` object in the `Connection` class, make it `public` and use it both from the class itself and both from the main function?

Comment: This sounds like an Idea, gonna try this!

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant, or the same, with a [very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381085/qtsignals-and-slots-vs-cmessage-passing). You can check my answer there. In short, a more complete/tested solution than building you own infrastructure may be [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) will probably be enough for almost all of your use-cases. In case you really need multiple event receivers, have a look at the [`multifunction` (multicast delegate) proof of concept](https://github.com/klmr/multifunction) I wrote.

It allows you to write code that is syntactically similar to C#:

```
void f(int n) { cout << "f: " << n << "\n"; }

util::multifunction<void(int)> event;

event += f;
event += [](int n) { cout << "[]: " << n << "\n"; };

event(42);
```